# rcpp: removing NAs in a moving window calculation

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

My idea is to calculate several statistics in a moving window (2 by 2).
For example, the code below calculate the mean value in a moving window. 
It works well when the input data hasn't got NA values, however gives bad results (NAs are treated as the lowest int) when NAs are in the dataset.
Can you guide me how it can be improved - for example by excluding NA in these calculations?

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix get_mw_mean(arma::imat x){
  int num_r = x.n_rows - 1;
  int num_c = x.n_cols - 1;

  arma::dmat result(num_r, num_c);

  for (int i = 0; i < num_r; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < num_c; j++) {
      arma::imat sub_x = x.submat(i, j, i + 1, j + 1);
      arma::ivec sub_x_v = vectorise(sub_x);

      arma::vec sub_x_v2 = arma::conv_to<arma::vec>::from(sub_x_v);
      double sub_mean = arma::mean(sub_x_v2);
      result(i, j) = sub_mean;
    }
  }
  return(wrap(result));
}

/*** R
new_c1 = c(1, 86, 98,
           15, 5, 85,
           32, 25, 68)
lg1 = matrix(new_c1, nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
get_mw_mean(lg1)
new_c2 = c(NA, 86, 98,
           15, NA, 85,
           32, 25, 68)
lg2 = matrix(new_c2, nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
get_mw_mean(lg2)
*/
```

Cheers,
Jot

Comment: What behavior are you looking for if an `NA` is detected?

Comment: Probably the best idea is to exclude NAs in these calculations.. (I've updated my question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things are happening here:

1. The matrix input type, `arma::imat`, is a *signed* `int`, but `NA` and `NaN` are only present in `float` or `double` types. In essence, `int` cannot have a `NA` or `NaN` placeholder by design. Thus, the conversion that occurs is to drop to the `INT_MIN`.
2. The need to subset out `NA` or `NaN` values in *C++* for `int`s.

So, the way forward is to be bale to detect this `INT_MIN` value and remove it from the matrix. One way to accomplish this is to use [`find()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#find) to identify *finite* elements that do not match `INT_MIN` and [`.elem()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat) to extract the identified elements.

For cases involving `double`, e.g. `arma::mat`/`arma::vec`/ et cetera, consider using [`find_finite()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#find_finite)

## Implemented

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat get_mw_mean_na(arma::imat x){
  int num_r = x.n_rows - 1;
  int num_c = x.n_cols - 1;

  Rcpp::Rcout << x <<std::endl;

  arma::dmat result(num_r, num_c);

  for (int i = 0; i < num_r; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < num_c; j++) {
      arma::imat sub_x = x.submat(i, j, i + 1, j + 1);
      // Conversion + Search for NA values
      arma::vec sub_x_v2 = arma::conv_to<arma::vec>::from( 
                                        sub_x.elem( find(sub_x != INT_MIN) ) 
      );

      result(i, j) = arma::mean(sub_x_v2);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

## Output

```
new_c1 = c(1, 86, 98,
           15, 5, 85,
           32, 25, 68)
lg1 = matrix(new_c1, nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
get_mw_mean_na(lg1)
#        [,1]  [,2]
# [1,] 26.75 68.50
# [2,] 19.25 45.75

new_c2 = c(NA, 86, 98,
           15, NA, 85,
           32, 25, 68)
lg2 = matrix(new_c2, nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
get_mw_mean_na(lg2)
#      [,1]     [,2]
# [1,] 50.5 89.66667
# [2,] 24.0 59.33333
```