# Can I compare with R_PosInf

Tags: r, rcpp

Is it reliable to compare with `R_PosInf` so that for any `double` `number`

```
number < R_PosInf == true
```

Comment: Not sure what you expect. For every finite number, you would always get `true` here, right? (PS: `== true` is not necessary here)

Comment: Note that `NA < Inf` and `NaN < Inf` are both `NA`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012902/rcpp-removing-nas-in-a-moving-window-calculation/49013472#49013472

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy enough to try!

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool compToInf(double x) {
  return x < R_PosInf;
}

/*** R
compToInf(.Machine$double.xmax)   ## largest representable double
compToInf(Inf)
*/
```

#### Demo

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/so50229770.cpp")

R> compToInf(.Machine$double.xmax)   ## largest representable double
[1] TRUE

R> compToInf(Inf)
[1] FALSE
R>
```